# SWT application showing updated display in near realtime

Tags: java, swt

**Question:**

> Can you show any simple example or explanation of SWT display part(which updates the window/shell)? Or can you any sites that you think they are the best for SWT application development?

**Background:**

> I am new to SWT application and currently building an application for running some tests.
>
> It has a main display shell class with text area which keeps getting updated after user clicked on a run button.
>
> The run button starts another thread process which updates public static object such as AtomicCounter in the StartView class.

**Current Stage**

> The program seems running well, however, it does not update the text area in realtime.
>   Well, I can't say realtime but it shows a little bit delayed information.(I can say it's delayed because I print out on the console as well)
>
> It seems like I don't understand displaying concept of SWT well enough to do whatever I am trying to do with it.

**Goal**

> A. Main Display class which starts and stops C regardless of B running or not
>
> B. Threaded process which updates text area of A class with public static object of A
>
> C. Threaded process which does its job and updating public static object of A

**Example Code (Working Code)**

```
public class UnitTest {

    public static Display display;
    private Shell shell;
    public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static Text text;
    private TestThread test1 = null, test2 = null;

    public UnitTest()
    {
        display = Display.getDefault();
        this.shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE);
        this.shell.setSize(226, 120);

        text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setBounds(10, 10, 199, 19);

        Button btnStart = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnStart.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                test1 = new TestThread();
                test1.start();
                test2 = new TestThread();
                test2.start();
            }
        });
        btnStart.setBounds(10, 54, 94, 28);
        btnStart.setText("Start");

        Button btnStop = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnStop.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                test1.interrupt();
                test2.interrupt();
                counter.set(0);
            }
        });
        btnStop.setBounds(115, 54, 94, 28);
        btnStop.setText("Stop");

        this.shell.open();
        this.shell.layout();

        this.shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener(){
            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                shell.dispose();
            }
        });

        while(!this.shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if(!display.readAndDispatch())
            {
                //text.setText(""+counter.get());
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new UnitTest();
    }
}

class TestThread extends Thread
{   
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(i++ < 1000 && !this.isInterrupted() )
            {
                UnitTest.counter.getAndIncrement();
                try {
                    TestThread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }

                if(UnitTest.display.isDisposed())
                    return;

                UnitTest.display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      if (UnitTest.text.isDisposed())
                        return;
                      UnitTest.text.setText(""+UnitTest.counter.get());
                    }
                  });

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Existing thread...");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This helps too. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/UpdateaSWTprogressbarfromanotherthread.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should carefully use UI updates from separate threads. Please, read this:

http://goo.gl/At8hC

Comment: Thanks for the link.
Updating Text within while(!this.shell.isDisposed()) will increase CPU to 99%.
Updating Text within TestThread wouldn't increase CPU like within while.
But the question is that, do I have to put display.async for every class whenever I want to update any component of what's on display?